# In Eureka First Bootstrap mode if client starts on a random port number, its registring with port 0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm using spring cloud Brixton.M4 and spring boot is v1.3.1, with eureka first approach and application starts on random port server.port=0 but its register it self at port 0 with eureka server.
here is my bootstrap.properties file

```
server.port=0

spring.application.name=course-composite-service

spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
spring.cloud.config.label=config-dev
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId=config-server

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8002/eureka/
```

and below its the log

```
2016-01-11 18:36:50.286  INFO 17233 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_COURSE-COMPOSITE-SERVICE/192.168.17.178:course-composite-service:0: registering service...
2016-01-11 18:36:50.288  INFO 17233 --- [           main] .w.c.c.CourseCompositeServiceApplication : Started CourseCompositeServiceApplication in 5.325 seconds (JVM running for 5.856)
2016-01-11 18:36:50.321  INFO 17233 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_COURSE-COMPOSITE-SERVICE/192.168.17.178:course-composite-service:0 - registration status: 204
```

and eureka dashboard shows

```
COURSE-COMPOSITE-SERVICE        UP (1) - 192.168.17.178:course-composite-service:0
```

why its not registering with the actual port its running?
i'm providing other eureka configurations from the Config Sever they are

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=10
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=5
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false
eureka.instance.metadataMap.hostname=${vcap.application.application_uris[0]}
eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId=${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
```

Comment: It's been very difficult for that particular case. Why do you need a random port number?

Comment: I guess the port in which the service will run should be provided by the platform, suppose i have a machine on which many application run, in that case i need to know the available port before deploying. This issue further increase, as routes defined in zuul with service id stops working. Though if i dockerize the application i need static port, still if i can run a application on ramdom port it should behave same as providing static port.

Comment: Unfortunately, the integration with eureka, eureka first bootstrap and random ports if extremely difficult because of the way eureka works.